# Ruby Strings, Loops, and Arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, loops

If given an array `l = Array.new` with `l` being filled with text of an essay.

What would be the easiest method to create a new string, loop through each line of the array and then add each line of the array to the newly created string?

Comment: Is l an array of lines or an array of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_string = l.join ''` should do the job fine.

A more imperative solution is the following:

```
my_string = ''
l.each do |line|
    my_string += line
end
```

Comment: `l.join` will serve just as well as `l.join ''`